# How to install Crystal Reports for .Net 3.5 Winforms application

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, installation, inno-setup, crystal-reports-2008

We have a VB.Net Winforms (x86) application that uses the freely redistributable version of Crystal Reports. Although the application works fine on my test machine, when installing on a client's machine and trying to print a report from the application, the error: The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine ... is displayed.

The inno-setup includes the CR redistributable "CRRedist2008_x86.msi" which was installed by the client during the installation. (We also tried running the "CRRedist2008_x64.msi" but received an "unsupported processor type" error).

I have read about Merge Modules that are prerequisites for .NET 1/2 (VS 2002/2005), but cannot find any useful information related to .NET 3.5 and am wondering if these files are still required and how to package and deploy them if they are in fact needed.

Any guidance on how to resolve this installation issue is much appreciated.

**Edit**
The Inno-Setup contains the following command that checks to see if CR is installed and if not the MSI is launched from the final setup form:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\CRRedist2008_x86.msi"; Description: "Crystal Reports"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Check: EnsureCrystalReports105Installed();
```

Comment: How are you currently running the redist MSI from your install script?

Comment: I have amended my question to include the Inno-Setup code used to launch the MSI.

Comment: I've edited it slightly to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually executing the MSI file.  You can see this by running your installer with `/LOG` and reviewing the resulting log file.

This is because MSI files cannot be directly executed -- they're data files, not programs.

To resolve this, you need to run `msiexec` instead, passing the MSI file as a parameter; eg.

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\msiexec.exe; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\CRRedist2008_x86.msi"""; ...
```

You should review the command line parameters accepted by msiexec and properties accepted by the MSI file to see if you want to do something different, eg. running the install silently instead of interactively.

Also, running it as postinstall is fine if this component is optional for your application and it can gracefully handle it not being installed.  If this is not the case then you should treat it as a prerequisite instead and always install it via `PrepareToInstall`.